# Combining multiple csv's by averaging each cell in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matrix

I have 7 csv files that each contain the same # of columns and rows. I am trying to merge the data from these into 1 csv where each cell is the average of the 7 identical cells. (ex. new-csv(c3) = average(input-csv's(c3)

Here is an example of what the inputs look like. The output should look identical (6 columns x 15 rows) except the values will be averaged in each cell.

[image]

So far I have this code to load the csv files, and am reading about making them into a matrix but I don't see anything about merging and averaging by each cell, only row or column.

```
listdrs = os.listdir(dir_path)
listdrs_path = [ dir_path + x for x in listdrs]
failed_list = []
csv_matrix = []
for file_path in listdrs_path:
    tickercsv = file_path.replace(string, '')
    ticker = tickercsv.replace('.csv', '')
    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)
    csv_matrix.append(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this in the directory with all of your csv files, you can use glob to find them all, then create a tuple of dfs using the `pd.read_csv()` with the optional parameter `header=None` depending on whether or not you have column names.  Then you can concat them, group by the index, and take the mean.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

files = glob.glob('*.csv')
dfs = (pd.read_csv(f, headers=None) for f in files)
pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).mean()
```